# How to display user data in an edit form using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an application for the company I'm working for in Flutter. We are using the MVVM (Model, View, ViewModel) architecture with the other developer I'm working with.

I would like to display user data from my ViewModel to my edit form (those data are fetched through our API).

The problem is: the data won't display to my view. I have access to it and I can print it (see screenshots below)...

What I tried so far :

- I used initialValue primarily and called, for instance, my 'lastName' variable (but it doesn't show anything)
- I tried using a controller for each field. With this method, it shows my user data but I then have a weird keyboard issue where each time I want to type some content, the cursor just goes to the start and deletes the word.

Also, I noticed that my variable can be displayed in a Text() widget.

I'm pretty clueless and I would really love to get an answer on this bug.

```dart
class MyAccountViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
    String _lastName;

    MyAccountViewModel() {
//      this._lastName = 'Hardcoded text';

        ApiHelper api = new ApiHelper();

        api.getUserData().then((Map<String, dynamic>response) {
            print(response);
            this._lastName = response['last_name'];
        });

        notifyListeners();
    }

    String get lastName => this._lastName;

    set lastName(String value) {
        this._lastName = value;
        notifyListeners();
    }
```

```dart
Widget editProfileForm(model, BuildContext context) {
        return Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                        initialValue: model.lastName,
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        );
    }
```

[current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTQfY.png)

[response after the API call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzNLW.png)

Comment: Can I see your `Form` widget source?

Comment: @Metr0me, for a quick a precise response, you need to include a basic runnable code of what you're doing or it'd just be guesses.

Comment: I simplified my code so you can better understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the answer I received in this post, I managed to find a working solution.

As advised in the previous comments, I needed to instantiate a controller and bind for instance "lastName" from my api response to controller.text.

Here is a sample code using the MVVM architecture :

```dart
class MyAccountViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
    TextEditingController _lastNameController;

    MyAccountViewModel() {
        _lastNameController = new TextEditingController();
        ApiHelper api = new ApiHelper();

        api.getUserData().then((Map<String, dynamic> response) {
            this._lastNameController.text = response['last_name'];
            notifyListeners();
        });
    }

    TextEditingController get lastName => this._lastNameController;

    set lastName(TextEditingController value) {
        this._lastNameController =  value;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

```dart
Widget editProfileForm(model, BuildContext context) {
        return Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: TextFormField(
                controller: model.lastName,
            ),
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Metr0me, have you tried using controller to update the value? It could look something like this,

- Initialize the controller as `final lastNameController = TextEditingController();`
- Assign text value to the controller when you have your model instance as,

```
MyAccountViewModel model = new MyAccount.....
lastNameController.text = model.lastName;
setState(() {}); //Refresh if you need to
```

- Assign lastNameController to your form field as,

```
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
     TextFormField(
        controller: lastNameController,
      ),
 ],
)
```

Comment: I will try your solution as soon as possible. I'm going to school and at the same time I'm working for a company (apprenticeship) and I don't have access to my project outside of it. 

I will reproduce the dev environnement and let you know. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No problem. Let me know.

Comment: Alright. Thanks to your comment I figured out how to implement it using the MVVM pattern. 

I instantiated a controller in my viewmodel and then binded the response from the api call to myControllerVariable.text and it now displays properly my variable.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

**Set the data to the text field**

```
setState (() { 
           lastNameController.text = model.lastName ;
             });
```

**Assign Controller to your textform field**

```
TextFormField(
                controller: lastNameController,
              ),
```